# converting scanned pdf from white background to black

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

hello everyone I have this book in pdf format and it is obviously was created using Scanner what I want to do is paint all pages background color from white to black and the text from black to white (night mode)

I am aware of the accessibility option in Adobe Acrobat that will allow you to do such thing but this method doesn't work on scanned documents

so please if you have any program to convert white-background-pdf to black-background-pdf or a for example a program that will invert the entire color of the screen (including pdf) it will be very helpful about the second method i tried using windows high contrast but it didn't change the background of the book.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Refer to this article may it helps you. https://www.sodapdf.com/blog/how-to-add-or-replace-a-background-colour-in-a-pdf-document/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse the **display** of a document in some PDF viewers, such as free [Sumatra PDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html). The steps to make all text **and** images show in inverse coloring in Sumatra PDF:

[image: Sumatra PDF Advanced Settings]

- Open a document in Sumatra PDF.
- From the menu (the icon with three lines) select *Settings>* | *Advanced Options...*. This should open *SumatraPDF-settings.txt* in your text editor.

[image: SumatraPDF-settings.txt]

- Change the FixedPageUI *TextColor* to #ffffff and *Background Color* to #000000.
- Save the file (acceding to UAC request) and display should change immediately.

[image: Sumatra PDF inverse colors]

Comment: great thanks a lot thats why I like  open source projects

Comment: windows only executables

Comment: @vwvan, of course Sumatra runs well under wine on Linux... as do many of my favorite Windows applications, such as IrfanView, 7-Zip, usw.

Comment: nice product. improve your delivery experience and consider adding the other half of the world of Mac users to benefit from it as well.

Comment: For Mac users, use wine: https://www.howtogeek.com/263211/how-to-run-windows-programs-on-a-mac-with-wine/

Answer (score 0):

SumatraPDF has many ways to access invert command via `-invert-colors` on command line, instant `i` hot key or one of your choice, or setting gamut in advanced settings.txt, or via external DDE, or internal command options.
[image]
[image]

HOWEVER by definition it is whole RENDERED page, is inverted for display only, there is no document editor control for text as separated from images, to do that needs an Editor like Acrobat Pro. or similar temporary "Lite" functionality in Heavy Weight Acrobat Reader.